# Web Application - MySQL Transactions

Tags: mysql, transactions

I'm planning a web application that will allow concurrent access to certain tables--using Rails.  Does anyone have advice for implementing transactions?  Is it even necessary?

The application will run under a CentOS LAM configuration.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know that transactions and concurrency have a whole lot to do with each other.

The main reason to use transactions, as I see it, is to make sure that if you perform multiple operations on the database, that they either all work or all fail. See [this blog post of mine](http://jasonswett.net/blog/why-you-should-use-database-transactions/) for more details on that.

So in other words, I'd say no, you don't have to worry about transactions as a way to address your concurrency situation. (I could be wrong, though.)

Comment: Also, doesn't any web app allow concurrent access on its tables to some extent? Once you get enough activity, I think you would inevitably get multiple users accessing the same tables at the same time. I think the ability to handle concurrency is just built into the RDBMS. I don't know that you really need to do anything special. (Again, I could be wrong.)

Comment: Also, there are a couple O'Reilly books, Large Web Applications and Building Scalable Web Sites, that you might want to check out. I haven't read them myself but I imagine they might be relevant.

Comment: I can see how my reference to concurrancy might be ambiguous in the context of transactions, but I'm referring to the need to lock the resources in support of the transaction.  I guess the RDMS locks the resources until it is done with them-on a per row/table basis--but I would assume it wise to lock all of the relevant resources pertinent to a transaction for proper normalization.  I guess I'm just seeking advice and insight into this aspect.

Comment: Hmm. Maybe you could edit and rephrase your original question? And I think instead of normalization you might have meant data integrity?

Comment: Normalization anomalies equal an integrity failure.

Answer (score 0):

Transactions and concurrence are not related. Transactions are needed in cases when you apply several actions  over the DB (usually, but not necessarily, to several tables) if the failure of any one of them would provoke an inconsistent state of some sort- be it with the already existent data or if the failed action was supposed to establish a requisite for the actions that follows it (for example: if fails the insertion of a new record that will be parent of others that would be inserted by the next actions). So in those cases,  you need to guarantee to apply  the related actions only if they are all successful or if they weren't,  to rollback then  all the previously executed related actions to return to the initial state that existed before the first of such actions were executed

Comment: In some cases, you might want to use transactions to assure data integrity (normalization) pertaining to the state of a certain record--taking into consideration concurrent access by two users who try to update the same row(s) in a particular table(s).